# Ionic 2 - Google map not working on android device

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic2

I am using ionic to build an app that shows a google map.

I got this to work on the browser correctly. and as a matter of fact it worked on my android device from last night till about 4 hours ago. been battling with why since.

The only clue i have now is this; wheni check the network tab in the debug too while the app is running on my phone, the last request is always this

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/AuthenticationService.Authenticate?1sfile%3A%2F%2F%2Fandroid_asset%2Fwww%2Findex.html&4sAIzaSyBI_QvVmgUwxUmXW8InZ5_Qf7Os8XieFxo&callback=_xdc_._dwgej7&token=81132
```

[image: Network tab requests for the device]

Or something similar. But on the browser(chrome) it runs that request and then runs several other requests after that.

[image: Network tab requests for the browser]

my guess is somthing is wrong with that request when its made via the device. the status is `200 Ok` it doesn't show 404 or anything. it just doesnt make any other requests and according to the browser network tabs there are about a dozen more requests it should make.

i'd like to point out that the initiator of the request is the google maps api script i included in my index.html and my API key is included in both.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1):

I might be late here, I had a similar problem i did the following and it solved the issue for me.

Please update - `cordova platform update android`

Please install - `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist`

If u already have it installed remove it and reinstall it.

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

to your config.xml file.

add the following permissiond to AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

try `ionic run android`
This worked for me.:P
u can give a try.